# How feasible is Roku app development with Marmalade?

Tags: c++, marmalade, roku

Marmalade can be used to make Roku apps in C++. From their website, they seem to encourage game dev in Roku. If I want to make a normal TV channel app in Roku with some graphics, how feasible will it be to make the app using Marmalade?

Answer (score 0):

App development is possible, though Marmalade is very game tailored.

However, can't make a TV channel, since in Marmalade there is no video streaming API (i.e. cannot play network stream). Moreover, the UI will be a pain - you'll have to create your own widgets (buttons, windows, menu/lists).

The cheapest Marmalade licence that includes Roku will [cost you $500/yr](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/shop).